# Replace for-each loop with lambda expression

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm just refactoring some of my old projects to use features of Java 8.

```
int counter = 1;
for (Checker checker : checkers) {
    if (counter < checkers.size()) {
        checker.setNextChecker(checkers.get(counter++));
    }
}
```

Here's kinda Chain of Resp pattern. And I need to set next checker for every checker in the list, excluding the last one.

Still can't find the way to use Stream API here :)

Comment: I would leave it with a `for` loop. Better readable and I see no advantage of streams here.

Comment: @lexicore is this any better in terms of readability https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006972/replace-for-each-loop-with-lambda-expression/50007953#50007953 ?

Comment: @Aominè I really don't see why it should be better than a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: @lexicore good shout, I guess I was more focused on using streams as the OP requested for it.

Comment: @Aominè You're absolutely correct, this was the OPs question and you gave a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `IntStream.range`:

```
IntStream.range(1, checkers.size())
         .forEach(i -> checkers.get(i-1).setNextChecker(checkers.get(i)));
```

or using a for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < checkers.size(); i++) 
      checkers.get(i-1).setNextChecker(checkers.get(i));
```

Comment: Also one could write a `for`-loop without `get(i)`.

Comment: @lexicore I am assuming you mean the for-each loop or also known as the _enhanced for loop_ ?, if so wouldn't that make things a little bit less readable than the current for loop?

Comment: Thanks, that's something I was looking for)
I agree, that Stream API is not the best choice here, but I was not able to find that solution fast, so I asked this question here.

Answer (score 1):

A crazy alternative:

```
Iterator<Checker> currentIt = checkers.subList(0, checkers.size() - 1).iterator();
Iterator<Checker> nextIt = checkers.subList(1, checkers.size()).iterator();
while (currentIt.hasNext()) {
  currentIt.next().setNextChecker(nextIt.next());
}
```

I guess that you could also write it with a single iterator:

```
Iterator<Checker> it = checkers.iterator();
Checker previous = it.next();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  previous.setNextChecker(previous = it.next());
}
```

But assuming your list is small, and `RandomAccess`, I'd just stick with an index-based loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checker.size()-1; ++i) {
  checkers.get(i).setNextChecker(checkers.get(i+1));
}
```

Streams aren't really a benefit here.

Comment: `previous.setNextChecker(previous = it.next());` Seems crazy too :)

Comment: @user7 yes, it's confusing enough that I had to try it to convince myself it would evaluate correctly.